# MongoDB 5.0+ requires a CPU with AVX support. Container failed to start

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to run mongo:6 in docker container with docker compose file but it always gets exited with warning.

> Docker version : 23.0.4, build f480fb1

> Docker-compose version: v2.17.2

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.8'
services:  
  mongo-db:
    container_name: mongo-db
    image: mongo:6
    volumes:
      - ../psvolumes/mongo6:/data/db
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=mongo
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - mongo_network
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
    mongo_network:
        driver: bridge
```

> docker compose up

**Output:**

```
[+] Running 2/1
 ✔ Network ams-api_mongo_network  Created                                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 ✔ Container mongo-db             Created                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
Attaching to mongo-db
mongo-db  | 
mongo-db  | WARNING: MongoDB 5.0+ requires a CPU with AVX support, and your current system does not appear to have that!
mongo-db  |   see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-54407
mongo-db  |   see also https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-5-0-cpu-intel-g4650-compatibility/116610/2
mongo-db  |   see also https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/485#issuecomment-891991814
mongo-db  | 
mongo-db exited with code 0
```

But it is always restarting and not get started

[Click here for docker logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DutpQ.png)

Comment: The latest one without AVX is 4.4.6. 
Ref: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/485

Comment: What platform (arch, CPU, etc) are you running docker on?

Comment: I am running on centos 9.

Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian

Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               44
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per socket:  1
    Socket(s):           4
    Stepping:            2
    BogoMIPS:            5320.00

Comment: I recently ran into this issue inside a VM running Alma Linux on Windows. Turns out having the virtualization Windows feature enabled breaks AVX support. Also, Core Isolation (memory integrity) uses Hyper-V and breaks much more.

Comment: If your hypervisor is proxmox, change CPU to host instead of kvm64 or etc. It'll resolve the issue same mine.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using proxmox just change cpu type (Hardware > Edit Processors) to host and reboot vm.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a container solving this problem

```
nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx/tags

Answer (score 0):

MondoDB needs the avx flag, but unfortunately it checks the reported-model and not the flags.
So if you want to keep your cpu-model as compatible as possible,
you have to add the avx flag and overwrite the reported-model:

Proxmox example:

```
cpu-model: mongodb_kvm64
    flags +avx
    phys-bits host
    hidden 0
    hv-vendor-id proxmox
    reported-model SandyBridge
```