# No connection to the nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, connection

I started my MongoDB from latest docker images (with `docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name test-mongo nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx`):

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY                   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE

mongo                        latest    01e8e54fc538   5 days ago     720MB

nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx   latest    e5a13eee06ee   4 months ago   685MB
```

because I was having the problem of [MongoDB 5.0+ requires a CPU with AVX support. Container failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76126384/mongodb-5-0-requires-a-cpu-with-avx-support-container-failed-to-start), thus I have to use the `nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx` image, it starts fine:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx

{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-23T03:19:39.491+00:00"},"s":"I", "c":"NETWORK", "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17}, "incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}} 
. . .
```

However, there can be no connection to the `27017` port:

```
$ telnet localhost 27017
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ telnet 127.0.0.1 27017
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                           NAMES
b7ecab4c2991   nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx   "/usr/local/bin/mong…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   test-mongo
```

Comment: Can you add more of the container logs? Because when reproducing the way you posted, I got a log entry a little further down that it's just bound to local interface. Hnce adding `--bind_ip_all` to the command  like `docker run --rm -ti -p 27017:27017 --name test-mongo nertworkweb/mongodb-no-avx --bind_ip_all` worked this out and allowed connections (testing with monsh)

Comment: BINGO @RickRackow, that ***is*** the answer, which I would gladly accept. thx.